# Производительность sqlite

Tags: android, android-sdk, orm

Нужен совет тех, кто пользовался GreenDAO. Скажите, что лучше использовать (с точки зрения производительности) при написании приложения связанного с бд sqlite, стандартные средства Android SDK или ORM GreenDAO?

Comment: Пара статеек с хабра на тему: [5 лучших ORM для Android](http://habrahabr.ru/company/yotadevices/blog/242559/)   и   [Что в ORM тебе моем? Околонаучный подход выбора ORM для Android](http://habrahabr.ru/company/sebbia/blog/245299/)

Answer (score 5):

SQLite (и инструменты SDK для работы с ней) в общем в работе [во много быстрее](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079568/orm-performance-is-greendao-faster-than-ormlite), чем GreenDAO - обертка для этой БД, написанная на Java, но некоторые операции greenDAO выполняет быстрее, что не мешает ей существенно проигрывать SQLite в "общем зачете"

Из всех ORM под андроид быстрее (примерно в два раза) SQLite только [Realm](https://realm.io/), написана на C++ "чистая" ORM (не базируется на SQLite, не является прослойкой, а использует собственный движок БД), но она пока в статусе беты (мне впрочем это не мешает пользоваться ей при каждом случае и вспоминать, как страшный сон, всю эту мороку с SQLite и обеспечением ее работы в андроид)

Comment: Не знаю, по моим ощущениям ```Realm``` проигрывает ```GreenDao``` по производительности, может быть я не достаточно сильно копал её.

Comment: @temq ну вот как то так [по производительности](https://plus.google.com/+WoraweeSattayavinij/posts/jCzzCeNLRyP)

Comment: Какие то странные у них результаты, на том же сайте GreenDao график сравнения с OrmLite где GreenDao значительно выигрывает. Для себя написал тестовый проект с вставкой 10000 записей в таблицу, где сравнивал GreenDao и Realm. Всегда побеждает GreenDao.

Comment: @temq Работа с БД не только вставка , основная доля идет на выборку, сортировку в запросе и тп. работу с данными в БД - здесь greenDAO проигрывает SQLite (в типовой модели полноценного использования БД), хотя некоторые операции он выполняет несколько быстрее. Там в статье есть ссылка на SoF с результатами по разным операциям. Насчет Realm - возможно вы неправильно написали транзакцию (например вставку "по одной" записи через java-код)

Answer (score 4):

`GreenDao` использует стандартные средства `Android SDK`. Она только генерирует за вас оптимизированный код, который бы вам самим пришлось писать без использования ORM. По производительности `GreenDao` будет побыстрее в некоторых моментах, например в селектах, чем самописный код. Это достигается из-за того, что для заполнения сущности из курсора `GreenDao` генерирует примерно следующий код:

```
public class SomeEntity {
    public SomeEntity(int id, String text, boolean isBoolean, int someNumber){
        //...
    }
}

SomeEntity entity = new SomeEntity(
    cursor.getInt(0),
    cursor.getString(1),
    cursor.getBoolean(2),
    cursor.getInt(3)
)
```

В то время, как вы сами бы написали примерно так:

```
SomeEntity entity = new SomeEntity(
    cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ID_COLUMN)),
    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TEXT_COLUMN)),
    cursor.getBoolean(cursor.getColumnIndex(BOOLEAN_COLUMN)),
    cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER_COLUMN))
)
```

Т.е. во втором случае тратится дополнительное время на поиск номера колонки по названию. Так же, вы можете посмотреть сгенерированные `GreenDao` классы для работы с БД и посмотреть что скрыто под капотом. Кто знает, может вы сами пишете достаточно быстрый код и вам не нужна никакая ORM.